# Showing that the gradient is orthogonal to level surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

It is well known that the gradient of a function (which is sufficiently well behaving) $g(x)$ is orthogonal to its level surface, for example $g(x)=0$. I have seen the following derivation of this fact in a book I am following:

> We first note that at any point on the constraint surface the gradient $\nabla g(x)$ of
>   the constraint function will be orthogonal to the surface. To see this, consider a point
>   $x$ that lies on the constraint surface, and consider a nearby point $x + \epsilon$ that also lies
>   on the surface. If we make a Taylor expansion around $x$, we have $g(x + \epsilon) \approx g(x) + \epsilon^T\nabla g(x)$. Because both $x$ and $x+ \epsilon$ lie on the constraint surface, we have $g(x) = g(x+ \epsilon)$ and
>   hence $\epsilon^T \nabla g(x) \approx 0$. In the limit $||\epsilon|| \to 0$ we have $\epsilon^T \nabla g(x)=0$, and because $\epsilon$ is then parallel to the constraint surface $g(x) = 0$, we see that the vector $\nabla g$ is normal
>   to the surface.

I am trying to build a complete proof out of this description. By the definition of differentiability it should be:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\dfrac{|g(x + \epsilon) - g(x) - \epsilon^{T}\nabla g(x)|}{||\epsilon||}=0 \tag{1}$$

Since $x + \epsilon$ is assumed to be on the level surface, we have $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\dfrac{|- \epsilon^{T}\nabla g(x)|}{||\epsilon||}=0$. But the problematic part is we only consider $\epsilon$ which causes $x+\epsilon$ to be on the level surface. The classic delta-epsilon limit evaluation covers all possible $\epsilon$, so I can't imagine a way to modify this to work with only "feasible" $\epsilon$, as stated in the description. Moreover, in the limit $||\epsilon|| \to 0$  $\epsilon$ disappears and I can't see how we can say that it is parallel to the surface there; it just does not make sense.

So, how can we build a proof which follows the given description above? I think the definition of the derivative at $(1)$ is the starting point but I can't see how it should go on.

Comment: If you put the denominator $\| \epsilon\|$ inside the numerator you can regard $\frac{\epsilon^T}{\| \epsilon\|}$ as a unit tangent vector to the level surface at $x$. Hence the limit tell to you that such unit vector is perpendicular to the gradient. Can this help you?

Comment: I considered doing that, I don't see how this makes it easier to evaluate the limit. Can you elaborate it more?

Comment: What is your definition of tangent space at the point $x$ of the level surface ?.  Perhaps my question seems extrange to you, but from what you comment to the other user it seems to me that you need to focus in such a definition. When I made my comment I assumed that your definition is the following: the tangent space $T$ at $x$ is the linear space (passing through $x$) which contains all the limits of secant lines. In particular it contains all the limits or sublimits of sequences of the form $\frac{\epsilon^{T}}{\|\epsilon\|}$ which are the generators of $T$.

Comment: I have the following definition of tangent space in my mind (which is a little troublesome to construct):  We have the function $f(x)$ of $n$ variables, which is differentiable. The level surface is $f(x)=k$ and at a point $p=(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ where we have $f(p)=k$, we can use implicit function theorem and build a function of $n-1$ variables, $g(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ around a $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ neighborhood of $p$ such that $f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},g(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}))=k$.

Comment: Then we will have $n-1$ tangent vectors to the surface at $p$, derived from the implicit function $g$: $u_1=(1,0,\dots,0,\partial g(p_1,\dots,p_{n-1})/\partial x_1)^T, \dots, u_{n-1}=(0,0,\dots,1,\partial g(p_1,\dots,p_{n-1})/\partial x_{n-1})^T
$.

The tangent plane to $p$ is finally the plane which contains all of these vectors.

Comment: Without lost of generality you can assume $p=(0,0,0,\cdots,0)$. Put $\epsilon^T := (t, 0,0,\cdots,g(t,0,0,\cdots,0))$. Now just observe that $\frac{\epsilon^T}{\|\epsilon\|}$ tends to  $\frac{u_1}{\|u_1\|}$. Then by the limit in your definition of differentiability $u_1$ is perpendicular to the gradient at $p$ as you wanted to show. Repeat the argument for $u_2,u_3,etc$ just by changing the position of the letter $t$ in the definition of $\epsilon^T$.

Comment: I cannot see how $\frac{\epsilon ^T}{|| \epsilon ||}$ tends to $\frac{u_1^T}{||u_1||}$ ? But it is clear that $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\epsilon^T}{t}  = (1,0,0,\dots,\dfrac{\partial g(0,0,0,\dots,0)}{\partial x_1})$,                                                                                                               which is the definition of the partial derivative. How are these related?

Comment: $\frac{\epsilon^T}{\| \epsilon \|} = \frac{(t,0,0,\cdots,g(t,0,0,\dots,0))}{\sqrt{t^2 + g^2(t,0,0,\dots,0)}} = \frac{(1,0,0,\cdots,\frac{g(t,0,0,\cdots,0)}{t})}{\sqrt{1 + (\frac{g(t,0,0,\cdots,0)}{t})^2}}$ taking limit as $t \to 0$ you get $\frac{u_1}{\| u_1\|}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the following consequence of differentiability, rather than the definition.  First, I’ll introduce some notation.  Suppose $g$ is a function on (an open subset of) $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Let 
$Dg(a)$ denote the Jacobian matrix 
$$ \left[ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(a)…\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}(a)\right],$$ and for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $D_{v}g(a)$ denote the directional derivative of $g$ at $a$ in the direction of $v$.  If $g$ is differentiable, then for any $v$ we have
$$D_vg(a) = \nabla g(a) \cdot v.$$

To use this result, let $a$ be a point on the level surface.  If $v$ is tangent to the level surface at $a$, then we have
$$0 = D_vg(a) = \nabla g(a) \cdot v.$$
Therefore, $\nabla g(a)$ is orthogonal to any vector in the tangent plane of the level surface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know the notion that at $a$, if we want to stay on the surface, we need to move parallel to the tangent plane, but actually, $v$ can be outside of the tangent plane: Let $b$ another point on the level surface, which is very close to $a$. Then the vector $b-a$ is not parallel to the tangent line ("Almost" parallel). In the method you describe, we assume that it is known that $v$ should be a vector in tangent plane a priori. I want to derive the result more directly, without making such assumptions.